# I want to show $e^{-\alpha t}B(e^{2\alpha t})$ is a Gaussian process.

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

Let $B(t)$ be Brownian motion. Show that $e^{-\alpha t}B(e^{2\alpha t})$ is a
Gaussian process. Find its mean and covariance functions.

thanks .

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have to prove that if $(t_1,\dots,t_d)$ are non-negative numbers and $(a_1,\dots,a_d)$ real numbers, then $\sum_{j=1}^da_jX_{t_j}$, with $X_{t}=e^{-\alpha t}B(e^{2\alpha t})$, is Gaussian.

For $d=2$, we write 
$$a_1X_{t_1}+a_2X_{t_2}=a_1e^{-\alpha t_1}B(e^{\alpha t_1})+a_2e^{-\alpha t_2}\left(B(e^{2\alpha t_2})-B(e^{2\alpha t_1})\right)+a_2e^{-\alpha t_1}B(e^{2\alpha t_1}).$$
We then rearrange the terms and use the independence of increments of Brownian motion. From this computation, we can get a formula for the characteristic function of $(X_{t_1},X_{t_2})$.

Comment: how to find the mean and covariance.

Comment: The mean is not hard to compute (what is $\mathbb E(X_t)$?). For the covariance, pick $t_1\lt t_2$ and in $X_{t_1}\cdot X_{t_2}$, you have to make to appear the increments of Brownian motion.